# AbstractMethodError while running finch/finagle application

Tags: scala, web-services, finagle

I am trying to run my application and I get this error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsStatsReceiver
```

My code is:

```
object Main extends TwitterServer {

  implicit val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectProvider.objectMapper

  val appConf = ConfigFactory.load()

  def main(): Unit = {
    statsReceiver.counter("posts")
    statsReceiver.counter("login")
    // configuration
    val port = appConf.getInt("8090")
    val db = new CommDb()
    val service = Api.makeService(db)
val server = Http.serve(":8080", service) //creates service

  def close(): Future[Unit] = {
    Await.ready(server.close())
  }
    Await.ready(server)
  }
}
```

It may be a bug, so what version of the library should I use, or I may just switch to a more stable web service library.

I see others with the same problem:

https://gist.github.com/edwelker/33e60108d62613434680ec13aa265611

**Update**

```
      "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.14.0",
      "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-circe" % "0.14.0",
      "com.tokbox" % "opentok-server-sdk" % "3.0.0-beta.2",
      "com.google.firebase" % "firebase-server-sdk" % "3.0.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % "it,test",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7",
      "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-jackson" % "0.14.0",
      "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-test" % "0.14.0" % "it,test",
      "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % "2.2.3" % "provided",
      "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "util" % "2.2.3",
      "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "proxy" % "2.2.3",
      "com.twitter" %% "finagle-stats" % "6.35.0",
      "com.twitter" %% "twitter-server" % "1.20.0",
      "com.twitter" %% "util-eval" % "6.34.0",
      "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.21",
      "org.slf4j" % "jul-to-slf4j" % "1.7.21",
      "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j" % "1.7.21",
      "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.21",
      "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "2.2.5" % "it,test",
      "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.1" % "it,test",
      "ru.arkoit" %% "finchrich-controller" % "0.1.1"
```

Comment: Well, which version _are_ you using? What are the other dependencies? Generally speaking, `AbstractMethodError` means there is a mismatch between classes which were on class-path during compilation and during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexey mentioned in his comment, this is a dependency mismatch problem.  sbt-dependency-graph is a useful tool to make sure all of your libraries are depending on the same version.

Comment: I switched back to Scalatra since I found Finch too hard to work with, due to this issue.  Perhaps someday I may try it again, as it seems promising, but I don't like to fight with the tools.  But, thank you for your response.